# Size of static libraries generated by Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a project tree in Xcode that looks like this: AppProject depends on ObjcWrapper which in turn depends on PureCppLib. ObjcWrapper and PureCppLib are static library projects. Combined, all sources barely reach 15k lines of code, and, as expected, the size of resulting binary is about 750Kb in release mode and slightly over 1Mb in debug mode. So far, so good.

However, ObjcWraper.a and PureCppLib.a are over 6Mb each in either mode. So the first question is why it is so. But more importantly, how can I ensure that those static libs do not include parts or all of the source code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up 'dead code stripping'.  In my experience the compiler optimizer (release mode) will not include code from libraries that is not referenced by your application. I am not in a place to do the googling for you, so give that a try first.  I will reply again once I get better placed.

Comment: Kenny, 

Dead code doesn't seem to be the problem here. The library that I called PureCppLib, plus appropriate wrappers, compiles to 500-900Kb on win, win mobile, macosx and android ndk if compiling to a dynamic lib (meaning that even most of dead code gets linked). But on iPhone dynamic libraries are not allowed, so I need to distritbute a static lib - and 6Mb just doesn't look right.

Comment: @shaft80: dynamic libs can have dead code stripping (and will have very aggressive dead code stripping with some linkers if an exported symbol file is used, for example); this certainly could be the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. Just out of interest I removed all code and all dependant libraries and the Obj-C binary still comes to 3MB. Of note is that this is a universal lib, the device alone is 1.9MB and the simulator build is 1MB. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to build your static library without debug symbols.  Find the "Generate Debug Symbols" build setting for the static library target in the Configuration you distribute, and make sure it is unchecked.